# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addText' of undefined in react-native-image-marker

Tags: react-native

i am getting this warning "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addText' of undefined" when i am trying to add text on image.
and unable to add text on image

```
Marker.markText({
src: uri,
text: "Watermark",
X: 300,
Y: 1110,
color: "#e9e9e9",
fontName: 'Montserrat-Light',
fontSize: 80,
shadowStyle: {
dx: 10.5,
dy: 20.8,
radius: 20.9,
color: "#e9e9e9"
},
scale: 1,
quality: 100
})
```

Comment: Can you please post compete Component?  addText is not even displayed above, so we can not see enough to even try and help.

Comment: hey thanks to reply there was a linking issue but now i am getting another issue that is ., ImageMarker.addText got 14 arguments, expected 13

Comment: Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189